Calculate speed from right triangle setup when direction is unknown
I´m trying to solve something that I can maybe best describe as trying to measure the speed of a water ripple when you don´t know the direction the ripple is travelling from and to. This would be impossible if you only measure the time the ripple passes through at two locations, but what if you use three locations that form a right triangle? For this, we assume the ripple is a straight line and not curved.
I can best imagine the problem in a coordinate system as seen below. I have sensor A, B and C. I know their exact position in the coordinate system. A straight line the travels through the coordinate system from any given angle. I will know the exact time the straight line passes each sensor. How do I from this information calculate the equation of the line and then the speed at which the straight line travels?
My first thought was to use Pythagoras Theorem, calculate the two speed vectors and add them, but the results doesnt look right.
Coordinate system displaying the problem. The distance from B to C is 10mm and C to A is also 10mm:


If this is a statistical problem, and not purely a mathematical one, then you must want to accommodate potential measurement uncertainty in the sensors.  What can you tell us about that uncertainty?

Hi @YvesDaoust Yes I thought your answer in that thread would be the solution but when testing it a bit more, it seems not to be the case unfortunately. In a scenario where the "line" travels in the direction of the hypotenuse, BC/tBC=2 minutes, CA/tCA =2 minutes, the result should be 3,53 mm/min but your formula gives 7,07 mm/min. I think I might have confused you by drawing 2 travelling "lines" in the other post. My point was that the "line" could come from any direction and is always unknown

As I commented your identical question, "If the distances $AC$ and BC are equal then you want to use the arctangent function (even better the atan2 function) on $t_C−t_A$ and $t_C−t_B$."

The evolution of the line can be parametrised exactly by three real-valued parameters $(x,y,t)$ consisting of a perpendicular velocity vector $(x,y)$ and the time $t$ that the line crosses the origin. If you write out the equations representing the times recorded by the three sensors in terms of these parameters, you then have a system of three equations in three unknowns which you can then solve.
